# Detecting input text field on screen with OpenCV (C#, emgu cv)

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0, emgucv

I am trying to detect input text fields on Windows form.

I am newbie in OpenCV, so I tried to use code (Emgu CV 3.x) from http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Shape_(Triangle,_Rectangle,_Circle,_Line)_Detection_in_CSharp

I've slightly modified that code, so I added a new imagebox5 and modified thresholds, because original code didn't detected any input field:

```
#region Canny and edge detection
            watch.Reset(); watch.Start();
            double cannyThresholdLinking = 120.0;
            cannyThreshold = 1;
            UMat cannyEdges = new UMat();
            CvInvoke.Canny(uimage, cannyEdges, cannyThreshold, cannyThresholdLinking);
            imagebox5.Image = cannyEdges;
```

As result imagebox5 shows rough outlines of fields, but no rectangles (input text fields) were detected.

How can I detect positions of each of input fields on such field with many input text fields?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach

- Convert image to grayscale
- Canny edge detection
- Find contours and filter using minimum/maxmium contour area

---

[image]

I implemented it in Python OpenCV but you can adapt the same strategy with C#

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
canny = cv2.Canny(gray, 50, 200, 1)

cnts = cv2.findContours(canny, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 10000 and area < 15000:
        cv2.drawContours(image, [c], 0, (36,255,12), 2)

cv2.imshow('canny', canny)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Hello, I am trying to reproduce your example witn python 3.6 on ubuntu 18 with X server, but I got as result two modal windows, every window is with black background on them. In what environment your example is working fine?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10, `opencv-python` v4.1.0.25, `opencv-contrib-python` v4.1.0.25, `numpy` v1.16.0, Python 3.7.4

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Based on your answer, I have another question - why detected rects are rotated in my case. Can you please take a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58283786/how-to-avoid-rotation-of-rects-detected-by-minarearect ?