# How to avoid rotation of rects, detected by MinAreaRect?

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0, emgucv

I am trying to detect text fields on Windows Form but `CvInvoke.MinAreaRect(contour)` returns rectangle, rotated by `-7.29419661` Angle.
[image]

My code is

```
        Image<Bgr, Byte> a =
          new Image<Bgr, byte>(@"d:/Art/documents/Projects/InputFieldsDetector/Images/Form345_1.PNG");

        imageBox1.Image = a;

        UMat grayed = new UMat();
        CvInvoke.CvtColor(a, grayed, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);
        imageBox2.Image = grayed;

        UMat canny = new UMat();
        CvInvoke.Canny(grayed, canny, 50, 200, 3);
        imageBox3.Image = canny;

        VectorOfVectorOfPoint cnts = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();

        UMat hierarchy = new UMat();
        CvInvoke.FindContours(canny, cnts, null, RetrType.Tree, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);

        Image<Bgr, Byte> justCountor = a.Clone();

        List<string> sizes = new List<string>();

        int count = cnts.Size;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            VectorOfPoint contour = cnts[i];
            var area = CvInvoke.ContourArea(contour);
            //if (area > 10000 && area < 15000)
            if (area > 200 && area < 300)
            {
                sizes.Add(area.ToString());

                Point[] pts = contour.ToArray();
                var forDraw = CvInvoke.MinAreaRect(contour);
                // forDraw.Angle = 0;
                //forDraw.Center.Y += 10;

                justCountor.Draw(forDraw, new Bgr(Color.DarkOrange), 2);
            }
        }
        imageBox4.Image = justCountor;

        List<double> result = sizes.Select(x => double.Parse(x)).ToList();

        result.Sort();
        sizes = result.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();

        File.WriteAllLines("c:/temp/qqq.txt", sizes);
```

Original image is:

[image]

If I uncomment section

```
            forDraw.Angle = 0;
            forDraw.Center.Y += 10;
```

sizes of detected rects are similar to sizes of fields...

Tell me, please, why returned rects are rotated and how to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see in the Canny output that the algorithm is interpreting the shadows as borders. The easiest way to fix that is prefilter the image with a threshold with a high value near to the white of the box background.

```
Image<Bgr, Byte> a =
              new Image<Bgr, byte>(@"d:/Art/documents/Projects/InputFieldsDetector/Images/Form345_1.PNG");

imageBox1.Image = a;

UMat grayed = new UMat();
CvInvoke.CvtColor(a, grayed, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);
imageBox2.Image = grayed;

UMat thresholded = new UMat();
CvInvoke.Threshold(grayed, thresholded, 128, 255, ThresholdType.Binary);
imageBox5.Image = thresholded;

UMat canny = new UMat();
CvInvoke.Canny(thresholded, canny, 50, 200, 3);
imageBox3.Image = canny;

VectorOfVectorOfPoint cnts = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();

UMat hierarchy = new UMat();
CvInvoke.FindContours(canny, cnts, null, RetrType.Tree, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);

Image<Bgr, Byte> justCountor = a.Clone(); 
List<string> sizes = new List<string>(); 
int count = cnts.Size;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    VectorOfPoint contour = cnts[i];
    var area = CvInvoke.ContourArea(contour);
    if (area > 200 && area < 300)
    {
        sizes.Add(area.ToString());
        Point[] pts = contour.ToArray();
        var forDraw = CvInvoke.MinAreaRect(contour);

        // forDraw.Angle = 0;
        //forDraw.Center.Y += 10;

        if (forDraw.Angle==0)
            justCountor.Draw(forDraw, new Bgr(Color.DarkOrange), 2);
    }
}
imageBox4.Image = justCountor;

List<double> result = sizes.Select(x => double.Parse(x)).ToList();
result.Sort();
sizes = result.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
File.WriteAllLines("c:/temp/qqq.txt", sizes);
```

Comment: I am tried to change values in `CvInvoke.Canny(grayed, canny, 10, 10, 3);` from 10 to 700, but in most cases rects are rotated or not detected (for highest values, similar to 700). Looks like thresholds didn't solve the problem

Comment: I think Canny its ok. I mean you should use CvInvoke.Threshold before Canny to obtain only the white boxes.

Comment: Wow, man, just WOW! You are genius! Thank you very much! Can you please change your answer? Please add this code to your answer to provide better to understand for other people - https://pastebin.com/ZBxf68Bb

Comment: Interesting, why if image was threshold with the code `UMat grayed = new UMat();
            CvInvoke.CvtColor(a, grayed, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);
            imageBox2.Image = grayed;

            UMat thresholded = new UMat();
            CvInvoke.Threshold(grayed, thresholded, 128, 255, ThresholdType.Binary);
            imageBox5.Image = thresholded;

            UMat canny = new UMat();
            CvInvoke.Canny(thresholded, canny, 50, 200, 3);
            imageBox3.Image = canny;`, now it's detect each field as two rects - one with Angle=0 and another one with Angle!=0?

Comment: Maybe is still the shadow, try to rise the threshold level like this:   `CvInvoke.Threshold(grayed, thresholded, 230, 255, ThresholdType.Binary);`

Comment: Interesting! When I changed it from 128 to 230, no any rect is detected. The value, with rects are detected is only 150. With upper value detection brokes, no any rects are detected.

Comment: One additional improvement would be to use Otsu's thresholding to automatically calculate the threshold value

Comment: I've tried `CvInvoke.Threshold(grayed, thresholded, 230, 255, ThresholdType.Otsu);`, and rects are detected now. But there are a lot of duplicates of fields, like in old code, with some value of Angle of duplicates. So, Otsu with 233, 255 didn't solved the issue, duplicates are still detected.